# Stop an audiofile from repeating XNA

Tags: c#, audio, timer, xna

I have a sound in my game

```
private SoundEffect sirenSound;
```

I have a model that uses collision detection to detect when it has collided with an enemy model.

```
if (enemySphere.Intersects(playerSphere))
{
    health--;
    sirenSound.Play();
}
```

This works fine only the problem I'm having is that another copy of the song is played every frame while the two models are colliding.

I thought maybe something like this would work

```
if(sirenSound.Play() == false)
   sirenSound.Play();
```

It's not working though, anyone know a quick workaround without having to use a timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Play()` method on `SoundEffect` is intended to be used in a fire-and-forget fashion.  For what you're doing, you want to use `SoundEffectInstance`, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx).

```
private SoundEffectInstance sfxInstance;
private SoundEffect sfx;

// ...

if (sfxInstance == null)
    sfxInstance = sfx.CreateInstance();

if (sfxInstance != SoundState.Playing)
    sfxInstance.Play();
```

...something along those lines.